# How do I combine "Omit" and "Pick"?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I wanted to change the type in my interface in a nested property.

I have tried to `Omit<Pick<A, "field">, "a">` and use intersection type `&`.

```
interface A {
    field: {
        a: string; // I want to change this to 'number'
        b: string;
    };
}

interface B {
    field: Omit<Pick<A, "field">, "a"> & { a: number };
}

let c: B = {
    field: {
        a: 1,
        b: "B"
    }
};
```

The code above gives me an error which says

```
Type '{ a: number; b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Pick<A, "field">, "field"> & { a: number; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'Pick<Pick<A, "field">, "field"> & { a: number; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pick` retruns an object type containing only the picked properties. So `Pick<A, 'field'>` will be `{ field: { a: string; b: string; } }`. You want the type of `field`, which you can get using an indexed type query `A[field]`(which will be `{ a: string; b: string; }`):

```
interface A {
    field: {
        a: string; // I want to change this to 'number'
        b: string;
    };
}

interface B {
    field: Omit<A["field"], "a"> & { a: number };
}

let c: B = {
    field: {
        a: 1,
        b: "B"
    }
};
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+TYCAGwBMAuTHPauCgZzClAHMBuZAeg+QElkB3OOGRgA9sgQALIcxRhJwOiPEByEAFcAtgCNoKqtVzb6jFqwPIAvuctYsoSLEQoAQpWoFi5ZAHlNwMAAeVABtACJPUjCAXQAaZDC4MIA+ZAAyTGRaZA0daCsbOyIIMAkKNwBedzxI72xDPGyARliLamMElzCLW2sgA)

If `A` has other properties, you can also extend a version of `A` with `field` omitted in order to preserve the other properties:

```
interface B extends Omit<A, "field"> {
    field: Omit<A["field"], "a"> & { a: number };
}
```